# Put Horizontal Recyclerview in the middle of vertical Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing a chat application. The chats appear in a vertical `recyclerview` . Now what i want to do is put a horizontal `recyclerview` between the chat texts  to display some items just like google allo or facebook messenger does. So after the horizontal `recyclerview` is displayed the chat should continue. I have no idea how to start implementing this? can someone point me towards any tutorials or tell how to do it?

This is my vertical recyclerview code

```
  private void attachMessagesToRecyclerView(final Query messagesReference) {
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageItemHolder>(Message.class,
            R.layout.adapter_item_message, MessageItemHolder.class, messagesReference) {
        @Override
        public MessageItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            AdapterItemMessageBinding adapterItemMessageBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.getContext()), viewType, parent, false);
            return new MessageItemHolder(adapterItemMessageBinding);
        }

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MessageItemHolder viewHolder, final Message message, int position) {
            int index = mUsersEmails.indexOf(message.getEmail());
            if (index != -1) {

                viewHolder.bindMessage(mUsers.get(index), message, MessagesFragment.this);

            }
                                viewHolder.bindMessage(mUsers.get(index), message, MessagesFragment.this);
                viewHolder.mAdapterItemMessageBinding.tvItemMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }


          viewHolder.mAdapterItemMessageBinding.showGarments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    showpDialog();

                    filterLink = message.getMessage();

                    ListOfdataAdapter.clear();



                    JSON_HTTP_CALL();



                }
            });

        }

    };


    mFragmentMessagesBinding.rvMessage.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mFragmentMessagesBinding.rvMessage.getAdapter().registerAdapterDataObserver(
            new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
                @Override public void onItemRangeInserted(int position, int itemCount) {
                    super.onItemRangeInserted(position, itemCount);
                    mFragmentMessagesBinding.rvMessage.scrollToPosition(position);
                }
            });
}
```

I want exactly like this

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? your question is too generic.

Comment: Like I said i have no idea how to even start

Comment: You know recyclerview, atleast you tried to create a recyclerview and add a horizontal recyclerview. You know where to start.

Comment: @Stackover67 check this https://github.com/msahakyan/nested-recycler-view

Comment: @Stackover67 this also https://medium.com/@mgn524/optimizing-nested-recyclerview-a9b7830a4ba7

Comment: I know how to implement horizontal recycler view my problem is showing it between the chats

Comment: I've Edited my question please take a look

Comment: a chat is based in multiples `viewHolders`. This is just another type that you need to create.

Comment: Did you ever create a chat app?

Comment: Yes. I did. I achieved the above functionallity